# Django serializer.data contains non existant value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### Context

I have an API endpoint that is used for devices to perform a check-in.

When a device is **not** known:

- A new `CustomerDevice` instance is created
- A new `DeviceStatus` instance is created related to the newly created `CustomerDevice`

API response:

```
{
    "customer_device_uuid": "646aaff6-debf-4281-bd7f-064dd6dc8ab8",
    "device_group": {
        "group_uuid": "ebd0990b-aeb5-46a4-9fad-82237a5a5118",
        "device_group_name": "Default",
        "color": "4286f4",
        "is_default": true
    }
}
```

When a device is known:

- A new `DeviceStatus` instance is created related to the device that made the request.

API response:

```
{
    "customer_device_uuid": "fbbdf1d1-766d-40a9-961f-2c5a5cb3db6e"
}
```

### The problem

The problem is the API response when a known device performs a check-in. The returned `customer_device_uuid` does not exist in the database and seems like a randomly generated `uuid`.

I want the API response for a known device to be the same as the API response for an unknown device.

`serializer.data` contains the random uuid untill the `else` statement. From there `serializer.data` contains the data I need in my response.

I tried to call `self.perform_create` in the `if` block. This results in `serializer.data` having the correct data for the response. However, this creates a new `CustomerDevice` and related `DeviceStatus` for every check-in no matter if the device is known or unknown.

My `views.py`:

```
class DeviceCheckinViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CheckinSerializer
    queryset = CustomerDevice.objects.all()
    http_method_names = 'post'

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        # if the device is known -> just log the data
        if CustomerDevice.objects.filter(device_id_android=serializer.validated_data['device_id_android']).exists():
            self.log_device_status(request)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

        # if device is not known -> link it to the customer and log the device data
        else:
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            customer_device = CustomerDevice.objects.get(device_id_android=request.data['device_id_android'])
            DeviceStatus.objects.create(
                customer_device_id=customer_device.customer_device_uuid,
                disk_space=request.data['disk_space'],
                battery_level=request.data['battery_level'],
                battery_cycles=request.data['battery_cycles'],
                battery_health=request.data['battery_health']
            )
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    # creates new instance with default group
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(group_uuid=get_default_group())


    def log_device_status(request):
        DeviceStatus.objects.create(
            customer_device_id=request.data['customer_device_uuid'],
            disk_space=request.data['disk_space'],
            battery_level=request.data['battery_level'],
            battery_cycles=request.data['battery_cycles'],
            battery_health=request.data['battery_health']
        )
```

My `serializers.py`

```
class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('group_uuid', 'device_group_name', 'color', 'is_default')


class CheckinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device_group = DeviceGroupSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='group_uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerDevice
        fields = ('customer_device_uuid', 'customer_uuid', 'device_id_android', 'device_group')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'customer_uuid': {'write_only': True},
            'device_id_android': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

### Desired outcome

The below API response either when a device is known or unknown.

```
{
    "customer_device_uuid": "646aaff6-debf-4281-bd7f-064dd6dc8ab8",
    "device_group": {
        "group_uuid": "ebd0990b-aeb5-46a4-9fad-82237a5a5118",
        "device_group_name": "Default",
        "color": "4286f4",
        "is_default": true
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Added `DeviceGroupSerializer()` to `serializers.py`

Relevant `models.py`:

```
# Customer table
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='customers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer'


# Device group table
class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    group_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    device_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_group_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'device_group'


# Customer_device table
class CustomerDevice(models.Model):
    customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_device_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    group_uuid = models.ForeignKey(DeviceGroup, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET(get_default_group))
    device_id_android = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # generated by client

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%r' % self.customer_device_uuid

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer_device'
        unique_together = (('customer_uuid', 'customer_device_uuid'),)  # composite key


# Device status table
class DeviceStatus(models.Model):
    device_status_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    disk_space = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    battery_level = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    battery_health = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    battery_cycles = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer_device = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_device")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%r' % self.device_status_uuid

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'device_status'
```

Comment: Are you sure that your "known" device has a `group_uuid` ? Because from the looks of it your serializer should have had serialized it anyway, so my bet is that it doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My "known" devices always have a `group_uuid`.

Comment: Could you put the models code and the DeviceGroupSerializer code as well? I want to simulate it on my end.

Comment: I added the relevant models code along with the DeviceGroupSerializer code.

Comment: I also updated the `views.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have instantiated a `Customer` with uuid `e73141ab-883c-44bc-8ce2-21b492cab03e` and a `DeviceGroup` with `is_default` set to `True` so that `get_default_group` can assign it.

Now what happens is that when I call the endpoint with:

```
{
  "customer_uuid": "e73141ab-883c-44bc-8ce2-21b492cab03e",
  "customer_device_uuid": "444b944a-4bcf-4ea2-8860-1d3ca82fd1d3",
  "device_id_android": "111",
  "disk_space": 10,
  "battery_level": 10,
  "battery_health": "good",
  "battery_cycles": 10
}
```

The response that is yielded is:

```
{
    "customer_device_uuid": "0d53c7d4-ce34-42ce-9dd8-5e7ea07c4438",
    "device_group": {
        "group_uuid": "5ee2f30e-bfd1-4f31-83ad-753d1d7220ad",
        "device_group_name": "",
        "color": "",
        "is_default": true
    }
}
```

It is exactly what you needed. My assumption is that either your `get_default_group` is not returning a default group.

The reason why the second time your serializer does not yield your desired output is because you are serializing the request data instead of the instance, and in the request data you don't have a `group_uuid` so you need to do the following:

```
# if the device is known -> just log the data
customer_device = CustomerDevice.objects.filter(
    device_id_android=serializer.validated_data['device_id_android']).first()
if customer_device:
    self.log_device_status(request)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    customer_device_serializer = CheckinSerializer(instance=customer_device)
    return Response(customer_device_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. Now when you do another check-in using the same parameters as your first call + the returned `customer_device_uuid`, it gives the weird response.

Comment: This solved it! Thank you tons for your help and effort! I banged my head against the wall today about how to solve this.